# can't capture ngSubmit when inside FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Trying to debug this one here.. I have a Reactive form with the following blocks:

- Main FormGroup
  [ formControls ]

  - ComponentX
  - Nested FormGroup
    [ formControls ]

    - ComponentX
  - FormArray
    [ formControls ]

    - ComponentX

ComponentX has a div with a DirectiveY.  DirectiveY has code to subscribe to the ngSubmit event of the main form.

The ngSubmit subscription works under the Main FormGroup and the Nested FormGroup but fails to work in the 3rd case when it is under the FormArray.

Here is a StackBlitz code example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/formarray-test?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello-message.directive.ts

When the submit is clicked the hello message should appear under the main Hello block.  The visibility is controlled by the directive which turns the hasSubmitted flag to true when the ngSubmit subscription fires.

Comment: Where does `control: AbstractControl;` come from? Here's working version https://stackblitz.com/edit/formarray-test-4sgy8s?file=src/app/hello-message.directive.ts

Comment: thanks!  That statement was missing it was `this.control = this.form.get(this.field);`  where form is just `(<FormGroupDirective>controlContainer).form`